# android : spinner prompt not showing in API >23

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm making an android app, and I'm using Spinners in Dialog Mode, defined as follows :

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/new_order_address"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
     style="@style/UnderlinedSpinner"
     android:layout_below="@+id/new_order_hint_address"
     android:prompt="@string/myString"
     android:spinnerMode="dialog"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

where the styles are

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal"> @color/colorPrimaryDark </item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary"> @color/colorPrimaryDark </item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight"> @color/colorPrimaryDark </item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated"> @color/colorPrimaryDark </item>
    <item name="android:minHeight"> 35dp </item>
    <item name="android:showDividers"> middle </item>
    <item name="android:divider"> @color/colorAccent </item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight"> 0.5dp </item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/input_label_horizontal_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/input_label_horizontal_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:textSize"> 14sp </item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/hintText</item>
</style>

<style name="UnderlinedSpinner" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

In API <23, everything works fine, but in API 23, the prompt is not shown. I've tried setting in from the java code, I've read all the similar questions and answers and have had no luck whatsoever.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot more of trial and error, I found out that the issue was in fact that the color of the prompt text was the same as the color of the background of the prompt (both white).

The reason behind it relays on the "textColorPrimary", which I'm not setting in the style of the spinner, but I did set in the style of the Tabhost where it is located. It looks like it inherited this property.

Therefore, the solution is just adding that parameter to the style, with the color desired.

The only thing I'm not sure is why this only happens in APIs > 23, and not the others.